# Cross domain ajax syncronous calls to retrieve plain text

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, security

I'm looking for a cross-browser solution to be able to make cross-domain syncronous calls. What I want to do is to call some PHP services that return plain text (no JSON or XML). And its important that the calls must be syncronous, not async.

Do you guys have any idea about this? Thanks!

Comment: **Do not make synchronous calls**.  They will freeze the browser until the server replies, severely annoying the user.

Comment: Well, @SLaks, the good news is that there's no cross-browser solution to making cross-domain AJAX calls anyway :-)

Comment: well, I know to freeze the browser is not the best, but it is how the current architecture works, it is a big app and I can't change that right now...

Comment: There doesn't exist a way to make AJAX calls cross-domain unless you set up a server-side file to return the other site's text. If you don't want to set the file up, you could do some iframe hacking, but iframes shouldn't be used now, so...

Answer (score 1):

If you make AJAX calls to sites not under your control, you can only use something like P-JSON for crossdomain calls, meaning: not plain text.

The best way to make cross-domain AJAX calls is to run a simple proxy script on your server, and make it fetch remote pages for you. If you cannot figure it out, drop me a comment here and I’ll help you with this, it’s like 4 lines of PHP (or whatever you use on server side).

Comment: hi, I can't put a PHP file in the same domain, cause it is an HTML5 app that runs in a mobile device. I implemented the php proxy solution, but unfortunately PHP (obvious) doesn't work in a mobile phone because it does not have an apache server

Answer (score 1):

First, to retrieve information cross-domain you'll have to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). For security reasons you can't load just anything cross-domain.

Second, for the love of everything holy in web development don't make the call synchronous. You should instead run a function as a callback when the load is complete that will fire all other necessary functionality. If your architecture can't handle this, then seriously reconsider the architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $.ajax with json as datatype here is sample code for that

```
<script>
  $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',

          url: 'http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?',  

          dataType: 'json',

          data: {tags: "cat",tagmode: "any",format: "json"},

          async: false,

          success: function(data) {   
                                      $.each(data.items, function(i,item){   
                                        $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");     
                                           if ( i == 3 ) return false;          
                                        }); 
                                   }
        });  

    </script>    

  <div id="images" name="images"></div>
```

Comment: Synchronous JSONP is not possible.